# Coffeescript : Best way to find a structure entry in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, compare

```
$scope.lastentries = []
e = {'min': $scope.minFoc, 'max': $scope.maxFoc, 'pas': $scope.pas}
$scope.lastentries.push(e)
```

I want to find if e is already stored in the array:
Unfortunately, e in $scope.lastentries does not work.
It seems it's not looking at all the fields, probably comparing some "references".

Of course, I can loop within the array and compare all the structure field by field.
But is there an easier way ? Something like in but that would compare all the fields.

So far, I'm doing:

```
v = $scope.lastentries.filter (x) -> x.min == e.min and x.max == e.max and x.pas == e.pas
$scope.lastentries.push(e) if v.length == 0
```

If someone has more "compact" / better of doing it, please share.
Thanks !

Comment: It's not looking at *any* of the fields; objects are compared by ID. You can only do this by manually iterating over the array and comparing whichever field or fields you want to use to test for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) (which is really lightweight so there should be no problem including it).

Using it, you can check using it's `findWhere` function:

```
v = _.findWhere $scope.lastentries, e
$scope.lastentries.push(e)  unless v?
```

If no match is found, or if the list is empty, `v` equals `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe underscore's _.indexOf would accomplish what you are looking for:

```
 _.indexOf($scope.lastentries, e)
```

will return the index position of e if contained in the array, else it will return -1

Comment: I don't think that's the right answer. Check @meagar's comment on the question.

Comment: i see. maybe _.isEqual instead of comparing each field indpendtly would make the code slightly more comapct